# Disable outlining permanently for JSON and CSHTML files?

Tags: visual-studio

Is it possible to disable outlining *permanently* for cshtml and json files? I can do it for C# but for some reason those file types don't allow it.

Also can't see how to prevent format on paste in JSON files. VS always makes a big mess of my file every time I paste. (I realize I can undo once to restore formatting, but still it's very jarring and randomly scrolls the page around.)